# Error linking with static Boost::Python library on Ubuntu x64

Tags: python, gcc, boost, linker, ubuntu-10.04

I've been trying to build a small Python module for x64 linux in runtime-link and link static configuration and unfortunately with no success. I'm using using Boost::Python v.1.47 on Ubuntu x64 10.04 with gcc 4.4.3 and Python 2.6.5 environment.

I've build Boost::Python manually using **b2** with no problems with options set to:

```
toolset=gcc variant=release address-model=64 link=static runtime-link=static
```

Next' I'm trying to build my module (pydsrc.cpp) using **bjam** with the same options, but it fails at the gcc linker stage. Below are the last lines from the build stage:

```
...
gcc.compile.c++ ../bin.v2/libs/python/build/gcc-4.4.3/release/address-model-64/link-static/runtime-link-static/object/function_doc_signature.o
gcc.archive ../bin.v2/libs/python/build/gcc-4.4.3/release/address-model-64/link-static/runtime-link-static/libboost_python.a
gcc.link.dll bin/gcc-4.4.3/release/address-model-64/link-static/runtime-link-static/pydsrc.so
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.3/crtbeginT.o: relocation R_X86_64_32 against `__DTOR_END__' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.3/crtbeginT.o: could not read symbols: Bad value
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

"g++"    -o "bin/gcc-4.4.3/release/address-model-64/link-static/runtime-link-static/pydsrc.so" -Wl,-h -Wl,pydsrc.so -shared -Wl,--start-group "bin/gcc-4.4.3/release/address-model-64/link-static/runtime-link-static/pydsrc.o" 
 "../bin.v2/libs/python/build/gcc-4.4.3/release/address-model-64/link-static/runtime-link-static/libboost_python.a"   -lutil -lpthread -ldl   -Wl,--end-group -static -m64
```

On Win7 x64 using msvc9 toolset I compiled it with no major difficulties, but I cannot success on Ubuntu. Has anyone come across similar problem or know what might be a solution? Any help or clue how to properly build the module would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Try include the PIC (position-independent code) compile flag via the cxxflags directive. So in your case something like:

```
toolset=gcc variant=release address-model=64 cxxflags=-fPIC link=static runtime-link=static
```

Comment: I've tried this also with recompiling the boost library with fPIC - unfortunately with no luck. I've gave up and dropped the static version compiling my module in a dynamic variant, but thanks for answer.